# Problem reading registers from Carlo Gavazzi EM24-DIN.AV5 using Python / ModBUS

Tags: modbus, raspberry-pi4, rs485, pymodbus

Dears,

I have a Carlo Gavazzi Energy Meter EM24-DIN.AV5 and I'm connecting it with Raspberry PI using USB/RS485 converter (zk-u485). The A/B/GND ports of USB-RS485 are wired with ports 41/42/43 of the device.

The device have a Joystick to configure the Serial Baudrate and the ModBus address (in my case they are 9600 and 3).

I used this sample of code to read some registers, but always receiving `Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received) D`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=3, stopbits = 1, bytesize = 8,  parity='N', baudrate= 9600)
val = client.connect()
if not val:
   print("******** Connection error *************")

while True:
#    rr = client.read_input_registers(address=37, count=2, unit=3);
    rr = client.read_input_registers(2,2,unit=3)
    print( rr);
```

Follwing the full debug log:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x3 0x4 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x2 0xd1 0xe9
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Transaction failed. (Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received))
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame - [] not ready
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 3
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - TRANSACTION_COMPLETE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 2
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x3 0x4 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x2 0xd1 0xe9
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Changing state to IDLE - Last Frame End - None, Current Time stamp - 1596433492.94
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Incomplete message received, Expected 9 bytes Recieved 0 bytes !!!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:RECV:
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame - [] not ready
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 3
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] No Response received from the remote unit/Unable to decode response
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - TRANSACTION_COMPLETE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 3
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x3 0x4 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x2 0xd1 0xe9
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Changing state to IDLE - Last Frame End - 1596433495.95, Current Time stamp - 1596433495.95
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Waiting for 3.5 char before next send - 4.01 ms
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
```

Following the ModBus protocol documentation:
https://www.ccontrols.com/support/dp/CarloGavazziEM24.pdf
[ModBus Addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uyYP.png)

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same results if you swap A/B, A/B naming is inconsistent between manufacturers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485#Signals).

Comment: Thanks @Bosz, after switching A/B wiring it worked fine.